# How can I fix iupac related alignment issues in TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, tocloft, chemmacros

Please have a look at the following picture of my TOC. You can see that there is an alignment issue with subsubsection 1.1.1 and subsubsection 1.1.2. The corresponding page number of subsubsection 1.1.1 is exceeding the right text limits and also the text right of 1.1.2 is exceeding the page limits.

[image]

I have to mention, that IPAC nomenclature `\iupac{TEXT-HERE}` is used here (also for the subsubsection heading of 1.1.1 and 1.1.2), to support correct hyphenation. Here is the minimal code sample which can be used to reconstruct this issue.

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
% --------- use tocloft package to format listings --------
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\@cftmaketoctitle}{} % remove automatically generated toc heading
% ---------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{chemmacros} % e.g. to support hyphenation for chemical names

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\section*{Table of Contents}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}

\tableofcontents{}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\subsubsection{\iupac{0,0'-((0-Loremipsumdol)Loremipsu)lor(0-(lore-lorem)-0-loremipsumdo)}
(00)}

\subsubsection{\iupac{0,0-Lo-lore-lorem-0-loremip-00-(0-loremipsumdol)-0,00-loremips-00L-loremmm[a,a][0,0,0]loremipsumloremi 0-lorem}
(00)}

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

What can I do, so that 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 comply with the text limits in my TOC?

Comment: your question would be a lot more understandable if you showed a complete small document that showed the problem, but can you not supply alternative text for the TOC `\section[short toc text]{long text for the section heading}`

Comment: I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: but is `\subsubsection[something]{\iupac{0,0'-((0-Loremipsumdol)Loremipsu)lor(0-(lore-lorem)-0-loremipsumdo)}(00)}` an acceptable answer, or do you need the full name in the toc, but reformatted to fit?

Comment: With the current dummy names, it is hard to tell, but you could provide possible breaking points using `|`, as for example in `\iupac{thio|ester}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No I do not want to use a replacement text in the TOC.

Comment: @leandriis There is no need to specify possible breaking points. Because IUPAC is capable of determining the acceptable breaking points itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the toc headings ragged

[image]

I just added one line to add fill glue as marked

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
% --------- use tocloft package to format listings --------
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\@cftmaketoctitle}{} % remove automatically generated toc heading
% ---------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{chemmacros} % e.g. to support hyphenation for chemical names

\edef\@tocrmarg{\@tocrmarg plus 2 cm}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\section*{Table of Contents}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}

\tableofcontents{}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\subsubsection{\iupac{0,0'-((0-Loremipsumdol)Loremipsu)lor(0-(lore-lorem)-0-loremipsumdo)}
(00)}

\subsubsection{\iupac{0,0-Lo-lore-lorem-0-loremip-00-(0-loremipsumdol)-0,00-loremips-00L-loremmm[a,a][0,0,0]loremipsumloremi 0-lorem}
(00)}

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With your answer we are almost where I would like to go. It looks good for subsubsection 1.1.1. But why is `(00)` moved to another line for subsubsection 1.1.2? There is enough space in the 2nd line of 1.1.2.

Comment: @wewa I didn't measure it but presumably there is not room to get in the minimal dotfiller

Comment: There is plenty enough space in the 2nd line of 1.1.2, even if `(00)` is in that line. In my original document there are lines where only two dots are printed. Could this be some LaTeX bug? Or do I need to modify something in the code?

Comment: @wewa oh I see what you mean, I just reposted it making the stretch a bit less stretchy 2cm finite stretch rather than fill infinite stretch

Comment: Great, this works perfectly. Thank you.